# in_array of 2 different sizes

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays. One for all the site and another one for sites with logos. I would like to user in_array to know which of the values from Arr1 are in Array2.

I am trying this:

```
for($i=0; $i<count($arr1); $i++){

    if (in_array($arr2[$i],$arr1[$i])) {
        echo "test";
    }

}
```

My Arrays:

```
Arr1
(
  [0] => 6
  [1] => 46
  [2] => 2
  [3] => 7
  [4] => 8
  [5] => 30
}

Arr2
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 2
  [2] => 8
)
```

Comment: What is the question? Have you read the [documentation](http://php.net/in_array)? It would help you feeding the right parameters into `in_array`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you *really* want to use is [`array_intersect`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php). The manual loop with `in_array` is more verbose and much slower.

Comment: Well what I want to do is loop through arr1 and if a value from arr2 matches arr1's value then do something.

Comment: @SamitPatel so, array_intersect and foreach on the result.